# jQuery Image picker

Tags: jquery, image, picker

I'm looking for a imagepicker in jQuery.

It should work similar to Gmail's way of attaching images to contacts:

1. There is an clickable, empty image
2. When clicked, a popup shows up with all the images and a searchbox
3. When a image is clicked, the popup disapears and the clickable image changes

Mootools or Prototype or even plain JS are welcome as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Has the question been resolved? Can you post any of the html you're working with? (I realise it's been about 18 months since asking, but I'm just going through unanswered jQuery questions...)

Comment: make a jsbin.com page and ill help you.

Comment: Is this question abandoned? I really want to help @Henk answer this because it's pretty easily done, overall.

Comment: @drachenstern Henk was `Last seen: Nov 7 '09 at 7:04` so sadly, there is probably nothing to be done here

Comment: @Pekka ~ Yes I know, hence the pain and upset involved here ;) ... I also left it for those who come along later reading and want to do it but figure nobody will help them ;)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: Not what he's looking for I think - `When clicked, a popup shows up with all the images and a searchbox`